# TTP Status 500 - Error instantiating servlet class com.zestedesavoir.servlets.Test>

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat

I got an error message when I tried to run on Eclipse a Dynamic Web Project.

The file web.xml is under WebContent/WEB-INF.

The servlet has been saved under Java Resources/src with the name "com.zestedesavoir.Test" and the servlet is named "Test.java".

There is the servlet code:

```
package com.zestedesavoir.servlets;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;

public class Test extends HttpServlet {

}
```

there is below the error message received when I run http://localhost:8080/test/toto

=================================================================

```
Jan 16, 2015 10:32:01 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Marking servlet Test as unavailable
Jan 16, 2015 10:32:01 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet Test
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.zestedesavoir.servlets.Test>
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1295)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:520)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:120)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1105)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:827)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1085)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1556)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1513)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
```

## at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

I tried many times by deleting the servlet and creating a a new one but I still got the same error message.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you notice that strange `>` character at the end of the class name?

That stray character is in both the exception message in the stacktrace AND the HTTP response message (apparently).

Somewhere in your webapp's configs you must have mistyped a class name.  I'd check the "web.xml" file first, but it could be somewhere else.